# Hough circle detection using opencv 3 and Python on RaspberryPi

Tags: python, opencv3.0, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run this code for hough detection on a raspberry pi with opencv3 as cv2 installed and running in a virtual environment wrapper

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the image, clone it for output, and then convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# detect circles in the image
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but when I try and run this code I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hough.py", line 12, in <module>
    output = image.copy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I am using a simple png image and have taken the example code from pyimagesearch.com.

What is that is here generating the error?

Comment: well, `image` is obviously not loaded. Wat is the output if you do a `print(args["image"])` before `image = cv2.imread(args["image"])`?

Comment: Copy error similar to above.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your image is not being read, to crosscheck it type in the command window:
image.
If you get the output as a numpy array then the issue can be something else.
How are you running this program? Its supposed to run via command line or terminal, by typing:

```
python program_name.py --image 'Path_of_image_on_which_you_want_the_program_to_operate'
```

If you are running on python3 on ubuntu or linux or MacOs type this:

```
python3 program_name.py --image 'Path_of_image_on_which_you_want_the_program_to_operate'
```

if you are working with windows, this will work:

```
py3 program_name.py --image 'Path_of_image_on_which_you_want_the_program_to_operate'
```

make sure to type it in the command line(CMD) or terminal and not in python's Shell as the program is supposed to be executed by argparser.